# "Has many through" relations - Product - Category - Subcategory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, relationship, has-many-through

I want to extend my current model scheme with a subcategory model.

Right now they look like this:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations

    ...
end



class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :articles, :through => :categorizations

  ...
end



class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    belongs_to :category
end
```

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the next step.
Guess I've been looking at the problem for a bit too long.

Article      has many    Categories
Article      has many    SubCategories

Category     has many    Articles
Category     has many    Subcategories

Subcategory  has many    Articles
Subcategory  has many    Categories

Comment: why not just   `class Subcategory < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
    belongs_to :article
    end`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for category and subcategory you should use gem `ancestry` and create something like:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :articles, :through => :categorizations

    has_ancestry
 end
```

here is documentatin: https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry